# no permita valores negativo ni mayores a 100 en Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, intellij-idea

Buen día, estoy intentado crear la estructura en el backend para que no permita valores negativos , ni mayores a 100 % en postman, y de acuerdo al porcenatje emita un mensaje.
la duda es crear la condición para que no permita valor negativo, ni mayores a 100% y dependiendo del porcentaje muestre un mensaje .

*ENTITY*

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Table(name = "institutotriangulo")
@Entity
public class InstuEntity implements Serializable {

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_empleado")
    private int id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "El nombre del producto es obligatorio")
    private String nombre;


    private String nameTecno;

    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]", message = "El campo solo puede tener numeros")
    private int anosxp;

    @NotNull(message="El valor es obligatorio")
    @Min(value = 2, message="El valor mínimo es 2")
    @Max(value = 100, message="El valor máximo es 100")

     private double porManejo; // % de manejo // 
    
    
    
    `private String nivelCono`; (Nivel de conocimiento)


**IMPLEMENTACION**
 
 @Override
    public ResponseEntity saveNewEmployee(InstuEntity instuEntity) { // guardar la informacion atrves de Jrepository //
           ResponseEntity responseEntity;

        var tecno = iInstiRepository.findByNameTecno(instuEntity.getNameTecno());



    if (tecno == null) {

    

try {

            do {
                    instuEntity.getPorManejo();
            } while (instuEntity.getPorManejo()<1);


        }catch (InputMismatchException e){

            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(e);

        }

        if (instuEntity.getPorManejo() <= 30) {
            iInstiRepository.save(instuEntity);
            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Tienes Conocimiento Semillero/Junio ");
        } else if (instuEntity.getPorManejo() <= 69) {
            iInstiRepository.save(instuEntity);
            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Tienes Conocimiento junio/Semi junior ");

        } else {
            iInstiRepository.save(instuEntity);
            responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Tienes Conocimiento Senior/ Super sayayin modo GOD  ");

        }

    } else {

         responseEntity = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Ya existe la tecnologia");
    }


    return responseEntity;
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
   @PostMapping
public ResponseEntity postSaveEmployee(@RequestBody InstuEntity instuEntity){
```

return iInstuService.saveNewEmployee(instuEntity);

```
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo usar el api de validaciones de Java ( javax.validation ), solamente debes usar unas pocas anotaciones a nivel de entidad dejando tu código mas configurable y por tanto mantenible

Comment: ¿Qué hace `instuEntity.getPorManejo()`? Si devuelve el mismo valor todo el tiempo vas a tener un loop infinito en ese `do..while` cuando `getPorManejo` sea menor que 1. Tu código no hace mucho sentido, así que por favor, aclara lo que quieres hacer y coloca de ser posible el código de tu entidad. Todo ahí está bien raro (sobretodo ese do..while).

Comment: Esta variable [instuEntity.getPorManejo()]  es en Entity (porcentaje por manejo = nivel de conocimiento de una tecnologia, que de acuerdo al % se muestra un mensaje del nivel de conocimiento ), tengo duda es en el do while, para que no permita ingresar Num negat=  public class InstuEntity implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id_empleado")
    private int id;
     private String nombre;
    private String nameTecno;
    @Pattern(regexp = "[0-9]", message = "El campo solo puede tener numeros")
    private int anosxp;
    private double porManejo;
    private String nivelCono;

Comment: con la  estructura del do while , es para que no acepte numeros negativos ni mayores a 100 % y despues de insertar el valor correcto muestre un menssaje